# Check if service exists in bash (CentOS and Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, service, centos

What is the best way in **bash** to check if a service is installed? It should work across both Red Hat (CentOS) and Ubuntu?

Thinking:

```
service="mysqld"
if [ -f "/etc/init.d/$service" ]; then
    # mysqld service exists
fi
```

Could also use the `service` command and check the return code.

```
service mysqld status
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    # mysqld service exists
fi
```

What is the best solution?

Comment: User `chkconfig <servicename>` to check its presence. The return value is 0 if it is present and 1 if not. `service <servicename> status` returns the status of a service.

Comment: `chkconfig <service>` only returns true if the service is configured to run in the current runlevel (according to the man page I have here). `chkconfig --list` seems to have the desired behaviour here though (at the cost of success and failure output) but may or may not be any better than just checking for the existence of (and executability of) the init script itself.

Comment: In 2019, it appears that the answer may be best viewed through the eyes of systemd and systemctl.

Answer (score 38):

To get the status of one service without "pinging" all other services, you can use the command:

```
systemctl list-units --full -all | grep -Fq "$SERVICENAME.service"
```

By the way, this is what is used in bash (auto-)completion (see in file /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion, look for _services):

```
COMPREPLY+=( $( systemctl list-units --full --all 2>/dev/null | \
   awk '$1 ~ /\.service$/ { sub("\\.service$", "", $1); print $1 }' ) )
```

Or a more elaborate solution:

```
service_exists() {
    local n=$1
    if [[ $(systemctl list-units --all -t service --full --no-legend "$n.service" | sed 's/^\s*//g' | cut -f1 -d' ') == $n.service ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
if service_exists systemd-networkd; then
    ...
fi
```

Hope to help.

Comment: I like this method, makes the check very clear in the script. So far, it's working well for me.

Comment: This is good but not the best. Some services like `pure-ftpd` will not be listed in `systemctl list-units` until you start it.

Comment: @ToiletGuy: in which case, the sytemctl list-units will return empty, and the function will return the correct result

Comment: Do note: In Debian system it should be `systemctl list-unit-files --all | grep "pure-ftpd". ` Using `systemctl list-unit` will  not display the disabled service (but it only display enabled service). You can use my answer without having to print all unit files and filter the result which can be slower.

Comment: @MaXi32 And that a lack of superuser permissions (i.e., no `sudo` or root user caller) will return a reduced list of service files

Comment: @Nick Bull What I meant was, using `systemctl list-unit-files --all` will display all services including disabled service, but `systemctl list-unit` will display all but not disabled service. So, it's a syntax issue (specific to Debian) not related to permission. I'm on root, tried your suggestion putting sudo before systemctl doesn't work.

Comment: Are you talking about `list-unit-files` or `list-units`? I'm referring to the former

Comment: "in which case, the sytemctl list-units will return empty, and the function will return the correct result" - That does not make sense. You are checking if the service is exist and yes it does but it falsely reported it does not just because it was not running. In your case you should be `checking is_service_running(){}` not `is_service_exists() {}`

Answer (score 23):

Rustam Mamat gets the credit for this:

If you list all your services, you can grep the results to see what's in there.  E.g.:

```
# Restart apache2 service, if it exists.    
if service --status-all | grep -Fq 'apache2'; then    
  sudo service apache2 restart    
fi
```

Comment: "service --status-all" writes services on unknown state to stderr. It might be convenient to use `service --status-all 2>&1 | grep -Fq 'apache2'`

Comment: If you need to ensure only 1 service is found, a trick you can use is a space in front of the service name.
`if service --status-all | grep -Fq ' cron'; then
    service cron start
fi` as `cron` will also match `anacron`

Comment: Shorter way to check both stdout and stderr in Bash: `service --status-all |& grep -Fq 'apache2'`.

Comment: This will first ping each service, and see its status. It can be quiete long to ping each service...

Comment: @JoséF.Romaniello Hi, may I know what -Fq command does? I googled it but didn't get a proper explanation.

Comment: @SandunI believe it's telling grep to use `--fixed-strings` and run in `--quiet`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/grep.htm

Answer (score 12):

On a SystemD system :

```bash
serviceName="Name of your service"

if systemctl --all --type service | awk '$1 ~ '"/$serviceName/" >/dev/null;then
    echo "$serviceName exists."
else
    echo "$serviceName does NOT exist."
fi
```

On a Upstart system :

```bash
serviceName="Name of your service"

if initctl list | awk '$1 ~ '"/$serviceName/" >/dev/null;;then
    echo "$serviceName exists."
else
    echo "$serviceName does NOT exist."
fi
```

On a SysV (System V) system :

```bash
serviceName="Name of your service"

if service --status-all | awk '$NF ~ '"/$serviceName/" >/dev/null;then
    echo "$serviceName exists."
else
    echo "$serviceName does NOT exist."
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

In systemd (especially in Debian), it doesn't seems to work properly using the various answers from here. For some services like `pure-ftpd` if it's in disabled mode, it will not show up in service list when you trigger this command:

`systemctl --all --type service`

and when you start again the `pure-ftpd` with `systemctl start pure-ftpd` the list will appear again. So listing the service using `systemctl --all --type service` will not work for all services. Take a look [at this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517872/systemctl-list-all-possible-including-disabled-services/518894#518894) for more information.

So, this is the best code so far (improvement from @jehon's answer) to check if a service is exist (even it has status inactive, dead or whatever status it is):

```
#!/bin/bash
is_service_exists() {
    local x=$1
    if systemctl status "${x}" 2> /dev/null | grep -Fq "Active:"; then
            return 0
    else
            return 1
    fi
}


if is_service_exists 'pure-ftpd'; then

        echo "Service found!"
else
        echo "Service not found!"
fi
```

Explanation:

If `systemctl status` found a service, it must have a text 'Active:' we filter using grep and it would return 0. If there is no 'Active:' text it would return 1.

If `systemctl status` does not find the 'Active:' text, it will print out a standard error. So, I put redirection `2> /dev/null` to redirect the standard error. For example, if you are looking for the non existence service, you would get this error message if you don't put that error redirection:

```
Unit pure-ftpdd.service could not be found.
```

We don't want to have the above standard error message if you are doing scripting

EDIT:

Another method is to list out unit files which able to detect disabled service as pointed by @Anthony Rutledge for Debian system:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type service | grep -F "pure-ftpd"
```

But using this method will not always work especially for older system because some unit files might not be detected using this command as explained in [here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-May/042555.html). Also, using this method is slower if you have large unit-files that need to be filtered (as commented by @ygoe about heavy load on a small computer).

Comment: `list-unit-files` will not work for template units like `<service_name>@<argument>.service` since the command only lists the template file `<service_name>@.service`, not the activated service ID. Instead use `systemctl list-units`.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
if systemctl cat xxx >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo yes
fi
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I wonder why people hassle with piping to grep in other answers, when you can simply use the exit code, like it is shown here.

Answer (score 2):

To build off of Joel B's answer, here it is as a function (with a bit of flexibility added in. Note the complete lack of parameter checking; this will break if you don't pass in 2 parameters):

```
#!/bin/sh

serviceCommand() {
  if sudo service --status-all | grep -Fq ${1}; then
    sudo service ${1} ${2}
  fi
}

serviceCommand apache2 status
```

Comment: don't know why but seams like some service status is printed to std_err so I had to add 2>&1 before the pipe

Answer (score 2):

After reading some systemd man pages ...

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

... and systemd.services(5)....

... and a nice little article ...

https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-and-using-systemd

I believe this could be an answer.

`systemctl list-unit-files --type service`

Pipe to awk {'print $1'} to just get a listing of the service units.

Pipe to awk again to get the service names exclusively. Change the field separator to the period with -F.

awk -F. {'print $1'}

In summary:

`systemctl list-unit-files --type service | awk {'print $1'} | awk -F. {'print $1'}`

---

With variation and augmentation of the base solution, you can determine the state of your system's services by combining a `for` loop with `systemctl is-active $service`.

Comment: This takes very long to load on a small computer. I believe this does way too much compared to the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

service=mysql
status=$(/etc/init.d/mysql status)
print "$status"
#echo $status > /var/log/mysql_status_log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(service --status-all | grep -w "$Service")
if [ "output" != "" ]; then
    #executes if service exists
else
    #executes if service does not exist
fi
```

$Service is the name of the service you want to know if exists.
var will contain something like

```
[+]    apache2
```

if the service does exist

Answer (score 0):

extend from @jehon's answers. Simple grep `-Fq` option will easy lead to mistake I believe, if there are similar named service or applications.

However this?

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep -Pq '.*\s\Kxxx$'
```

Replace xxx with desired service or application name will match exactly the name.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, as `ps` command can be used in both Ubuntu&RHEL, this should be work in both platform.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep mysqld > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "mysqld service exists"
else
  echo "mysqld service not exists"
fi
```

Comment: This assumes it is running. I don't want to check if the service is running, I want to see if the service is installed.

Comment: Maybe this one help `service --status-all | grep mysql` in this way you can check if service installed or not, if installed it gives you result,if not no result for related service.