# if command A result has *not* in it, then do command B

Tags: linux, bash, salt

I have been tasked with what I'm sure is a basic bash script assignment. Essentially, I will run command A, and if that command result contains the word "not" in it, then it will kick off command B.

I have tried searching around for just such a bash script, or an example of something similar, but can't find anything. I'm sure that I'm just not searching for it right way which is half my problem. So what I have so far based on what little I can find is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ 'sudo service xyz status' = \*not* ]; then
    sudo service xyz status
else
```

Another detail: this is using the SALT stack. So this is a command checking if a service across many servers is running or not, and if it is great, do nothing. If it isn't, I want to start the process.

I'm  testing it just on my own dev box.

Comment: hundreds of a-priori apologies and thanks make your question *worse*, not better. Focus on the question! Yes, your formatting was way of, but that was easily fixed. If in doubt, use one of the **many** editors that have automatic code indention (though I'm not sure how many actually support shell scripts, but mine does). Generally, I'm in favor of people *shortly* explaining their background, but you basically used multiple paragraphs to say "I'm new to programming". Yeah, we can see that in your code, so this is a distracting zero-info.

Comment: You can use `grep` for that: `if sudo service xyz status | grep -qF '*not*'; then sudo service xyz status; else ...; fi`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951760/650884

Comment: thank you @gniourf_gniourf!

Comment: @DustinMac No, **not** an amateur mistake of "giving *too much **detail***". What you gave weren't details. It was redundant and unrelated info that was distracting. It's actually hard to give too much *detail*, but easy to be *too chatty*. But: no harm done, and enjoy the StackOverflow ride!

Comment: @MarcusMüller that's what I meant in too much detail. I'll save the pleasantries in the future. Really do appreciate the help. This is already been a great decision to join the community at large. So exciting to be in this career arch in my life!